# Check for user logged in with Active Directory in Java application

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

So I have looked around quite a bit to find the answer I'm looking for, especially on this site, without any luck or a way to get exactly what I want for this app.

It's a java application and I'm trying to interact with Active Directory in Windows Server 2012 R2 so the user won't have to log into this java application if they have logged into their machine by using Active Directory.

I've heard that there is some kind of token that is in place on the machine if the user logged in with Active Directory and I was hoping I would just be able to check for that token, get the username of the logged in user, and log them into the java app with that username (disregarding password). I would like to do this without having to authenticate against the AD server as well.

I'm not sure that this would be the most efficient way for management of Active Directory against this java app, but it's all I need given my situation.

Links are welcome and I'm sorry if this question has been asked before.

EDIT: This is assuming that the only information I have available is the username of the Active Directory user which will match the username in the java application. I also have server credentials but I am trying to avoid storing the server's password in any form.

Comment: You could use JAAS with the NTLM module.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you elaborate on that a little bit? I looked into NTLM with JAAS a little bit but all I could really find is still using the username and password to hit the AD server to authenticate credentials, which I'm trying to avoid. I might've missed something while looking though. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. Using the System.getenv("USERDNSDOMAIN") gives us the user@domain which is null if the user isn't logged in with Active Directory, which is enough in this case. Then we're using JAAS and a server conf file to get our LoginContext which gets the Subject from the logged-in user.

Hope this helps someone!

For example, here's the code:

```
//this returns the logged in user if they're authenticated with the ldap server (Active Directory)
public javax.security.auth.Subject getSubject()
{
    String ldapServer = System.getenv("USERDNSDOMAIN");

    if (ldapServer == null)
    {
      Logger.error("No \"USERDNSDOMAIN\" environment variable found");
      return null;
    }

    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "jaas.conf");
    System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "true");
    try
    {
      LoginContext loginCtx = new LoginContext("Server", new TextCallbackHandler());
      loginCtx.login();
      return loginCtx.getSubject();
    }
}
```

and the contents of the jaas.conf file:

```
Server {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=false
useTicketCache=true;
};
```

Comment: Hello, I know it's been awhile, but is there any chance you can elaborate on the "Then we're using JAAS and a server conf file to get our LoginContext which gets the Subject from the logged-in user." portion?

Comment: Sure! It's been a long time so I can't remember exactly how all of this works, but this is what I've got right now. Code posted above.